# Python CSV from JIRA with duplicate Sprint headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, jira

I'm using python 3.7.5

I have a CSV file which I got out of out Jira instance in order to see which issue were completed in which sprint.
Jira keeps track of every sprint the issue was in so if you export a CSV you will get multiple **Sprint** headers with data something like this:

```
Issue key,Issue Type,Status,Sprint,Sprint,Sprint,Sprint
OLS-526,Story,Done,Sprint #16,Sprint #17,Sprint #18,Sprint #19
OLS-871,Story,Done,Sprint #18,Sprint #28,,
OLS-165,Story,Done,Sprint 1,Sprint 3,Sprint #18,Sprint #19
OLS-868,Story,Done,Sprint #28,,,
```

What I need is to identify the **Sprint** the Issue was delivered in, so the right most of the **Sprint** columns, so I can then count how many issues were actually done in each sprint.

I've tried using the default python 'csv' and the DictReader like this:

```
import csv
with open('../OLS-tix2.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
  for row in reader:
    print(row['Sprint'])
```

but you only get the *last* **Sprint** column and blanks if there is nothing in that column. as the output of the above looks like this:

```
Sprint #19

Sprint #19
```

I could just use the normal csv reader and roll my own, but I figure there has to be a nicer way of doing this in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I did some more looking around and came across [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) which looks like might be a good tool for this job.
There are lots of examples and as a bonus I can do the flitering/pivoting using the [dataframes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) and [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) and [aggregating counts of ids](https://www.interviewqs.com/ddi_code_snippets/count_distinct_pandas)

This is what I ended up working for me:

```
import pandas as pd


csv_file = "../OLS-tix.csv" # where the file is at
ols_df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
finish_sprint_col = 'finish_sprint' # the column to put the actual Sprint thie issue was finished in
ols_df[finish_sprint_col] = "" # add the new blank column
sprints = ols_df.columns[ols_df.columns.str.contains('Sprint')] # get all the headers that contain the word sprint as they will be Sprint, Sprint.1 ... Sprint.N
for i,row in ols_df.iterrows():
  if not ols_df.at[i,"Status"] == "Done": # we only want to do this for "Done" Issues
    continue
  finish_sprint = False
  for header in sprints: # go through all the sprint cells for this row and get the last not empty one.
    if not pd.isnull(ols_df.loc[i, header]):
      finish_sprint = ols_df.loc[i, header]
  if finish_sprint:
    ols_df.at[i,finish_sprint_col] = finish_sprint

# get number of issue finished per sprint.
dones = ols_df[(ols_df.Status == "Done") & (ols_df['Issue Type'] == "Story") ].pivot_table(index=["finish_sprint"],values=["Issue key"], aggfunc=[pd.Series.nunique])
```

This is probably a simpler way to do this, but this seems to works for now...